# Mobile authentication using JWT

Tags: android, ios, rest, security, jwt

I need to authenticate users of a mobile application that communicates with a REST api.

After doing some research, I found 2 ways:

1. Firebase Authentication (No because I have my own database)
2. Use of JWT

So I have questions about JWTs :

**If I use an HTTPS connection, can someone steal the token ?** (no man in the middle for example)

**A new token has to be sent by the API for each request ?** (This way I can reduce the lifetime of the token ?).

**In order to avoid user reconnection, I need to use a refresh token, can it be another JWT?**

Answer (score 0):

1. It depends, if you store it in localstorage or sessionstorage it's possible to steal it with xss attack. If you store in on an httpOnly secure cookie it's harder. 
   but it's impossible to steal it from the request when you use https.
2. No, there is a token validity time, for example 1hour, 1day etc...
3. yes. it should be another token, it's called refresh token, you can
   read more about it here:
   https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/

Comment: 1. With the mobile application, I think it's only a local storage (for example: sharedPreference on Android), if I understood well with HTTPS the leak can't occur during the communication.

2. I have to resend one it will expire or I let it expire and send a new one with the refresh Token ?

3. If the refresh token is steal, the thief can generate infinite access token ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using your own database that is why JWT is the best option for you.

**1- If I use an HTTPS connection, can someone steal the token ?:-** 
Yes, they can steal the token, mitma is possible, but even if they will temper the token your server will get to know by validating the token and verify the issuer of the token (your client and server can use a private key to encrypt the response on client-side and decrypt and validate it on server-side)

**2- A new token has to be sent by the API for each request? (This way I can reduce the lifetime of the token ?).**
Yes, every token will be different a JWT token is an encrypted form of your post data and issuer, subject and other additional data. So if your post data is different every time the token will also be different.

**3- In order to avoid user reconnection, I need to use a refresh token, can it be another JWT?**
Another JWT is not required.

You can use Jawa JWT library:-  Visit https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt

And use this class to create and validate and decode JWT tokens.

```
public class JWTTokenVerifier {

public String CreateToken(String body) {
    String token = "";
    try {
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(Constants.APP_SECRET);
        token = JWT.create()
                .withClaim("body", body)
                .withIssuer("auth0")
                .sign(algorithm);
    } catch (JWTCreationException exception) {
        //Invalid Signing configuration / Couldn't convert Claims.
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("TOKEN IS > " + token);
    return token;
}

public void verifyTokenAndDecodeResponse(String token) {
    try {
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(Constants.APP_SECRET);
        JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
                .build(); //Reusable verifier instance
        DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);
        String payload = jwt.getPayload();
        Base64 base64Url = new Base64(true);
        payload=new String(base64Url.decode(payload));
        System.out.println("payload is " + payload);
    } catch (JWTVerificationException exception) {
        System.out.printf("Unable to parse token");
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: 1. If I use a private key on the mobile application, reverse engineering of the apk allow to  find the key ? (How mitm is possible thought HTTPS ?)
2.If my payload is as big as a messages list, we can send a big jwt ?
3. Thanks for code example

Comment: 1. you can use android signing key hash as a private key or you can save it on firebase get it on runtime, there are many options available for that and mitm is possible as the attacker can sniff it before https layer on application layer, I faced similar issue also rooted devices are a big problem.
2- Yes you can send large payloads.

Comment: With this solution, If I need to store the key associated to my client in the database, I will lose the advantages of JWT ?
In your experience, what is the best auth system? Is HTTPS + JWT (access and refresh tokens) enough or did I forget something ?

Comment: Firstly you don't need to store the private key for each and every client.
Every client and server will use one UNIQUE PRIVATE KEY.

Yes, HTTPS + JWT is enough.

Comment: Can you confirm this answer, please : 
I generate a key and store in the mobile app and in the server side.
My client send credentials mail +pwd using the key to auth server, the auth respond with access token + refresh token using the same key (but the sign of JWTs use an other SECRET stored only on server side).
The client take tokens and use to get ressources from REST api ?
All of this use HTTPS channel.
(An other answer is to use only HTTPS + JWT without private key )

Comment: The client will create a token by encoding the request (email + PWD or any other) with JWT using the secret key and will send the token to the server, the server will validate the token with the same private key,if it is valid then decode it use it and then the server will create a token for the response using JWT and the same private key and will send that token to the client then the client will again validate the token with the same private key if it is valid then the client will decode the token.
Only one private key will be used on both client and server-side no need to refresh token.

Comment: Thanks, but by reverse engineering or by rooting the phone, it's possible to retrieve the key, right?